# Http Requests: how to identify a machine using multiple IP addresses

Tags: linux, networking, http, linux-networking, ip-address

I have an http server. Is it possible to identify a machine, which is making http requests to my http server using different IP addresses?

In other words, is it possible to identify a machine, by something which is not the IP address used for making the request?

Comment: With `JavaScript`) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site

Comment: There is no general solution for this. What greater goal are you trying to achieve? That information may narrow the scope of this question to something with a pragmatic answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can have some success by looking at the User-Agent header that gets sent.  If they're a sophisticated attacker they may vary this though.  If you think a human is using a browser on a computer to access your server but from multiple IPs, another way is you can use mod_rewrite (or some other method) to set a cookie on their browser and then watch for that cookie.

Answer (score 0):

With apache, you can integrate p0f and mod_pof to do a browser fingerprint.
Plz, check http://linuxbox.co.uk/p0f_php_fingerprinting.php